# Is there a function that is Riemann integrable but not monotonic and not piecewise continuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I know that continuous functions are Riemann integrable, piecewise functions are Riemann integrable and that monotonic functions are Riemann integrable.

I would like to know if there is a function $f$ that is Riemann integrable such that $f$ is not  picewise continuous and such that $f$ is not monotonic.

Thank you.

Comment: A better question title would be "Is there a function that is Riemann integrable but not monotonic and not piecewise continuous?" Note that continuity is stronger than piecewise continuity, so you can leave that requirement out.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: does piecewise mean finitely many pieces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Such a function exists. For example, let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
be defined by $f(x)=0$ if $x\in\{0,1\}\cup\left([0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}\right)$
and $f(x)=\frac{1}{q}$ if $x\in(0,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ and $x=\frac{p}{q}$,
where $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$ and $p,q$ are relatively prime. $f$ is
known as the Riemann function. It is well-known that the set of discontinuity
of $f$ is $(0,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}$, which is of Lebesgue measure zero.
By a characterization theorem (due to Lebesgue), $f$ is Riemann integrable.
Clearly, $f$ is not piecewise continuous nor monotone on any non-empty
open sub-interval of $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you ! What is the name of the characterization theorem due to Lesbegue ?

Comment: The characterization theorem has no name (but it is due to Lebesgue). It is stated as follows: Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. Then $f$ is Riemann integrable if and only if the set of discontinuity of $f$ has Lebesgue measure zero. You can find such theorem in any real analysis textbook.

Comment: Ok, thank you.       :)